# How to prevent bear bag line from tangling?

Tags: backpacking, bear-bags

While backpacking, I usually carry 50 feet of spectra cord (2mm) to be used as part of my bear bagging system. More often than I would like, I end up having to untangle the line before being able to use it.

Although my untangling skills are ever increasing, **how can I prevent the tangling of the cord** in the first place? A cord winder comes to mind. However, I'm also curious to find out about tips and tricks on how to properly store cordage when a winder may not readily be available.

Comment: great answer on a sister site: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/how-can-i-coil-up-a-rope-so-that-it-doesnt-get-tangled

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I typically wrap the cordage around my forearm from the notch between my thumb and forefinger around my elbow. I then take the excess cord at the end and wrap around the bundle 10+ times and secure the end of the line through.